# facebook - post as page on another page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've developed a facebook application.
I also have my own official facebook page.

I wish to post as my official facebook page to other pages walls.
When I try doing so I receive the following error:

```
(OAuthException) (#200) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include a target_id
```

How can I overcome this?
Is this even possible?

Comment: Hi can you please post your code?